# what ruby, rails, gem versions are supported for bundler 2.2.13?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I need the list of all the ruby versions, rails versions, and gem versions which are support `bundler 2.2.13`.
I am using `ruby 2.6.3p62`,  `gem 3.0.3`, `rails 4.2.11.3`. And my `bundler 2.2.33` which is not supported in `rails 4.2.11.3` and I want to replace it with `bundler 2.2.13` how can I do that?

Comment: According to [this table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html), even Rails 5.0 does not support Ruby 2.5. Therefore I guess you need to downgrade Ruby to at least 2.4 (2.2 is recommended) to be able to run your Rails 4.2.x application.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 only supports bundler 1.x. Newer Rails versions (i.e. Rails >= 5.0) support any bundler 2. Each Rails version supports varying Ruby versions. Check the release notes of your Rails version for details.

As such, you can either upgrade your Rails version to 5.x at least or downgrade your bundler to 1.17.3 (the latest bundler version before 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get all the supported gems that would support a particular `bundler` version. But you can check on a particular gem if it supports your `bundler` version or not. For example see this: https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.11.3 which says this version of `rails` requires `bundler >= 1.3.0, < 2.0` (in runtime dependencies).

This is usually added on the `gemspec` of the gem as far as I know. For example here is the `rails 4.2` gemspec: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/rails.gemspec which specifies the `bundler` version.

But getting an old version of `rails` to support a new `bundler` version is not just changing the `gemspec` there could be many things which might break so it is advisable to use the specified versions.